# Finding the starting location of specific consecutive values in every row

Tags: r, apply

I am kind of new to R and am still learning how to use all the functions. I'm stuck with this problem on my project, so would definitely appreciate any help!

I have the spending behavior data of customer 1, 2, 3, and 4 from Jan to Dec. Every row is a unique customer, and every column is the customer's spending activity of that month (1 is active, 0 is inactive).

```
+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    Name    | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Customer 1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |
| Customer 2 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |
| Customer 3 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
| Customer 4 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |
+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I am trying to find the "last" occurrence of 3 consecutive zero's in every row, if any, and locate the starting point of them. This would help me identify when the customer goes into "idle" or "hibernation" status.

The expected results would be:

```
Jun (or 6 as column index) for Customer 1
Sep (or 9 as column index) for Customer 2
Oct (or 10 as column index) for Customer 3, since the last 3-month occurrence begins at Oct instead of Sep
NA for Customer 4, since there's no such an occurrence
```

After going through some similar questions on stackoverflow, I figured using rle and apply might be the right approach, but I have been struggling with how to write this into actual code. Sincerely appreciate any idea!

Answer (score 0):

I would melt the dataframe so there are 3 columns:
Name, Month, Spending Behaviour.
I would then do a rollmean from the zoo package with a left align, subset for instances where the rollmean is 0 and pick the last observation for each customer.